# From Discrete Mathematics - Graph theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Describe a graph model that represents whether each person at a party knows the name of each other person at the party. Should the edges be directed or undirected? Should multiple edges be allowed? Should loops be allowed?

Answer (score 0):

The edges should be directed because it's possible that John knows Mary's name, but Mary does not know John's. This could happen if John is a private citizen in a town and Mary is the mayor of that town.

Multiple edges should not be allowed from one person to another, since a person either knows the other person, or not. The presence or absence of an arc is sufficient to represent this either/or reality. This also suggests that the graph need not be weighted.

Cycles of any length, including length one, should be allowed. Presumably, most individuals know their own names, though this is not necessarily guaranteed (consider a party-goer with total retrograde amnesia). So, many individuals will have self-loops. Also, it's likely pairs of people know each other's name, so loops between pairs of individuals are likely. Larger cycles are also likely.